# Python Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I am solving [this question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/find-digits) on HackerRank.

> ### Problem Statement
>
> You are given a number `N`, you need to print the
>   number of positions where digits exactly divides `N`.
>
> **Input format**
>
> The first line contains `T` (number of test cases followed by `T` lines
>   each containing `N`).
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <=T <= 15  
> 0 < N < 1010
> ```
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Number of positions in `N` where digits in that number
>   exactly divides the number `N`.

When I give the input

```
T = 1
N = 114108089
```

I get `ZeroDivisionError`

Even after using the `try` and exception, error handling technique in Python the answer I get is `0` instead of the correct answer `3`.

Code so far:

```
def find_digits():
    try:
        ctr = 0
        c = int(input())
        string_c = str(c)
        list1 = []
        for ch in string_c:
            list1.append(ch)
        for i in list1:
            print i
            b = int(i)
            if c % b == 0:
                ctr += 1
        print ctr
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print 0

test_case = int(input()) for s in range(test_case):
    find_digits()
```

Comment: def find_digits():
    try:
        ctr = 0
        c = int(input())
        string_c = str(c)
        list1 = []
        for ch in string_c:
            list1.append(ch)
        for i in list1:
            print i
            b = int(i)
            if c % b == 0:
                ctr += 1
        print ctr
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print 0

test_case = int(input())
for s in range(test_case):
    find_digits()

Comment: @enrico.bacis I have added the code above in the question.

Comment: So you had `ZeroDivisionError`, so you just wrapped the whole thing in `try`, and now you get `0` (that you are explicitly returning in that case)? **What did you expect?!** What effort have you made to figure out what the actual problem is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am inputing the number 114108089, but the program shuts down giving an output of 0 instead of 3. If you could look at the program or the link, You could help me a lot?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question; that is the same information you have already provided. What I am asking for is why you expected different and what effort *you* have actually put into figuring this out, as your code is currently doing exactly what you specifically told it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the digits in `N` are zeroes, so `b == 0` and when you try:

```
if c % b == 0:
```

you get a `ZeroDivisionError`. Rather than wrap the whole function in `try`, (which means you will *only ever get non-zero output for inputs that contain no zeroes at all*), wrap that one section:

```
try:
    if c % b == 0:
        ctr += 1
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Alternatively, check for non-zero values of `b` first:

```
if b and c % b == 0:
```

If you really want to get clever, the function can be done in one line:

```
sum(N % i == 0 for i in map(int, str(N)) if i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a division by zero error because the digits can be zero.

```
if c % b == 0:
```

Here b can be zero.